# change multiple classnames based on containing one word with greasemonkey

Tags: class, greasemonkey

i have classes with contain "day"

```
<tr>
<td class="old disabled day">1</td>
<td class="disabled day">2</td>
<td class="new disabled day">3</td>
</tr>
```

how to change that classes to only class="day" with greasemonkey

```
<tr>
<td class="day">1</td>
<td class="day">2</td>
<td class="day">3</td>
</tr>
```

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example based on your HTML

```js
document.querySelectorAll('td.day').forEach(item => item.className = 'day');
```